# Django user registration just stopped working

Tags: python, django

I have been working on a django registration script and it was working and without changing anything it stopped working and i'm not entirely sure why. When I register it takes me to the login page and says username and password don't match. It is as if it is not even passing the data to the views. I'm not sure here is my code it probably is just a django thing i'm doing wrong.

After further investigation, I realized that it is not calling the register function inside the views.py. 
[image]

I added some print lines to my register view to see if it was executing

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    print 'test'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        print form
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            save_userdata = UserProfile(username = form.cleaned_data['username'] , 
                                        title=form.cleaned_data['profile_title'], 
                                        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'], 
                                        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                                        about = form.cleaned_data['about'],
                                        user_score = 0,
                                        dob = form.cleaned_data['dob'],
                                        occupation = form.cleaned_data['occupation'],
                                        pub_date = datetime.now())
            save_userdata.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
    'register.html',
    variables,
    )




from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from ChompMe.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_page),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'), # If user is not login it will redirect to login page
    url(r'^register$', register),
    url(r'^register/$', register),
    url(r'^home$', home),
    url(r'^home/$', home),
    url(r'^register/success/$', register_success),
    url(r'^register/success$', register_success),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^gettoken/$', getToken),
    url(r'^addfriend/$', addFriend),
    url(r'^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$', friends),
)


@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            save_userdata = UserProfile(username = form.cleaned_data['username'] , 
                                        title=form.cleaned_data['profile_title'], 
                                        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'], 
                                        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                                        about = form.cleaned_data['about'],
                                        user_score = 0,
                                        dob = form.cleaned_data['dob'],
                                        occupation = form.cleaned_data['occupation'],
                                        pub_date = datetime.now())
            save_userdata.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
    'register.html',
    variables,
    )

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'success.html',
    )


#files.py
import re
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=30)), 
                                label=_("Username"), error_messages={ 'invalid': _("This value must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.") })
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=30)), label=_("Email address"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=30, render_value='False')), label=_("Password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=30, render_value='False')), label=_("Password (again)"))
    dob = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$', 
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=11)), 
                           label=_("Birthday YYYY-MM-DD"), error_messages={ 'invalid':_("This must be in the proper format YYYY-MM-DD")})
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=20)), label=_("First Name"))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=20)), label=_("Laast Name"))
    about= forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=90000)), label=_("About"))
    occupation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=40)), label=_("Occupation"))
    profile_title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required='True', max_length=40)), label=_("Profile Title"))

    def clean_userdata(self):
        self.cleaned_data['dob'] = self.dob    
        self.cleaned_data['first_name'] = self.first_name 
        self.cleaned_data['last_name'] = self.last_name 
        self.cleaned_data['about'] = self.about 
        self.cleaned_data['occupation'] = self.occupation  
        self.cleaned_data['profile_title'] = self.profile_title 


    def clean_username(self):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The username already exists. Please try another one."))

    def clean(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields did not match."))    
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block head %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="0">
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
    <a href="/">Login</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show your template with form?

Comment: {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block head %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="0">
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
    <a href="/">Login</a>
{% endblock %}

Comment: @GwynBleidD  there i included it please help i don't understand why its not executing the register code anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console shows your `POST` request goes to `/`, but it has to point toward `/register/`, right? Change the `action` in your form to given url:

```
<form action="{% url "register" %}" method="post">
```

+

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register$', register, name='register'),
    ...
)
```